# Content restraint when submitting edit of other users post

Tags: discussion

I wanted to make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357765/how-to-create-a-menu-in-electron-like-adding-compile-option-in-electron-for-c) question better readable by putting the code into a code block. I also wanted to remove at least the user signature.

But the system didn't let me submit the edit because it said the question was mainly code and I should add more description text.

I can understand that error if this was my own post, but I can't add content for another user.

My edit was probably not the most stellar one, but is this behavior as expected or did I do something wrong?

Comment: If "... it said the question was mainly code and I should add more description text" then it is probably correct to say so. So, *can* you add more descriptive text? Or is that better left to the question poster?

Comment: Well even if I could - should I add more description text? My edit would probably be rejected for changing the intent of the post. So I'm unsure what to do here. I'm not a pro at english language but I am at least able to make the code readable by formatting it. So it feels strange to just doing nothing at all.

Comment: @Rhayene Focus on editing posts that you can actually salvage.  Going around spending a bunch of time editing posts *that are still going to merit deletion even after your edit just isn't productive.  Rather than polishing turds, edit posts that will be at least acceptable by the time you're done editing them.

Comment: @Servy I see, thank you for the advice :)

Comment: Completely agree with servy, adding: feel free to downvote, and/or flag "unclear", and/or comment "it's not clear/tidy up your post" etc :)